# Program about how many times the number has been repeated

Tags: java

For example i want to find how many times 1 repeated in number 123900148
It must be write 2 times but i get wrong values for everytime

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
@author Başar Ballıöz

int counter = 0;
int repeat;
int tmp;


System.out.print("Enter A Number: ");
tmp = input.nextInt();
String number = Integer.toString(tmp);


System.out.print("Enter A Number You Want To Find: ");
repeat = input.nextInt();


for (int i = 0; i < number.length() - 1 ; i++) {    

    if (number.substring(i , i+1).equals(repeat))

    counter++;
}

System.out.println(repeat + " number " + counter + " repeated.");
```

i would like to see my output like:

```
number : 134211
number i want to find how many times repeated: 1
your number has repeated 3 times
```

Comment: By "but my code dont give *any* output" do you mean that `System.out.println(repeat + " number " + counter + " repeated.");` is not executed? Or maybe that it doesn't print *correct* values?

Comment: BTW why `tmp = input.nextInt(); String number = Integer.toString(tmp);` instead of `String number = input.next();`?

Comment: @pshemo Wrong values

Comment: please don't type in uppercase letters, it's hard to read.

Comment: Sorry for that i fixed it

Comment: @Pshemo I guess thats due to data validation. if `next` was used then the client is not only limited to numbers by any kind of data input, by using `nextInt` the client can only enter numbers otherwise the program would blow up. not sure whether letting the program blow up is the best response though... ;-).

Comment: @Aomine That is also my suspicion, but still this code doesn't feel fight. If OP wants to add number validation it should be done via `hasNextInt()` which doesn't prevent us from using `next()` if we want to have it as String.

Comment: @Pshemo definitely agreed, there are several things which can be said in regard to the code shown from what you've just mentioned and efficiency can also be improved. nonetheless seems to me they're still a beginner so understandable on my side.

Comment: You're problem might be the (- 1) in your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing a `String` against an `Integer` via `equals` hence you're not getting the expected result. instead convert the integer to a string prior to comparison:

```
 if (number.substring(i , i+1).equals(String.valueOf(repeat)))
```

Further, you could cache the result of `String.valueOf(repeat)` into a variable before the `for` loop to prevent a string object construction in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Excellent, very clear What is the difference between with String.valueOf and without it ?

Comment: `String.valueOf` converts the `int` into its string representation whereas without it the `repeat` gets boxed to an `Integer` and then suddenly you're performing a `String` and `Integer` comparison.

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing a `String` (returned by `number.substring(i , i+1`) to an `Integer`, so of course it will always return `false`.

Either compare two `int`s or two `String`s. Since you are essentially comparing two digits, comparing `int`s would be more efficient.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {    
    if (Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(i)) == repeat) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int counter = 0;
    int repeat;
    int tmp;

    System.out.print("Enter A Number: ");
    tmp = input.nextInt();
    String number = Integer.toString(tmp);

    System.out.print("Enter A Number You Want To Find: ");
    repeat = input.nextInt();

    while (tmp > 0) {

        if (tmp % 10 == repeat) {
            counter++;               
        }
        tmp = tmp/10;
    }

    System.out.println(number + " number " + counter + " repeated.");
```

Comment: Guys, i also deleted -1 in for (int i = 0; i < number.length() - 1 ; i++) part
Because it was created some problems when i entered long numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  I added some helpful output so you can see how it's indexed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CountChars {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter A String: ");
        Map<String, Integer> map = indexString(input.nextLine());

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter A Character You Want To Count (ENTER to exit): ");
            String repeat = input.nextLine();
            if (repeat == null || repeat.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("'%s' was repeated %d time(s).", repeat, (map.containsKey(repeat)) ? map.get(repeat):Integer.valueOf(0)));
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, Integer> indexString(String s) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println(String.format("'%s' has %d characters.  Indexing now.", s, s.length()));
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() ; i++) {
            String c = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
            if (!map.containsKey(c)) {
                map.put(c, 0);
                System.out.println(String.format("Indexing %s", c));
            }
            System.out.print(String.format("Incrementing '%s' from %d ", c, map.get(c)));
            map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
            System.out.println(String.format("to %d.", map.get(c)));
        }
        return map;
    }

}
```